# Programmatically set scroll index of react native VirtualizedList

Tags: react-native

I have a book reader application, I implement book content thorough react native Virtuallist. In some case it needs to scroll to some titles in the book that can be out of screen and not rendered yet. If I load whole book's content I faced some performance issue. I need a way to change Virtuallist index or shift it on paragraph selection. this is what I implemented so far but it scroll to bottom constantly to render paragraph I chose, And looks so ugly.

```
const getItem = (_, index, focusedRank) => {
   return data[index];
};

return (

  <VirtualizedList
    ref={(refs) => (flatListRef.current = refs)}
    data={DATA}
    initialNumToRender={20}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    getItemCount={() => data.length}
    getItem={(_, index) => getItem(_, index, focusedRank)}
    contentContainerStyle={{padding: 10}}
    onScrollToIndexFailed={(info) => {
      const wait = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
      wait.then(async () => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset({
          offset: info.averageItemLength * info.index,
          animated: true,
        });

        await flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
          index: focusedRank,
          animated: true,
        });
      });
    }}
  />
)
```

If I could change index or shift by focusedRank the problem's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Flatlist. And also Flatlist has onLayout you could implement it using regression algorithm or like that. By implementing it you have a simple time to navigate between paragraph anymore

Comment: Thanks I was trying to use React list like recyclerview on android but it fails

Comment: Yes and calculating text height is keypoint to solve this question